# Getting : Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() after rewriting a class

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

This is my xml:

```
<blocks>
    <mynamespace_mymodule>
         <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
    </mynamespace_mymodule>
    <adminhtml>
         <rewrite><catalog_product_composite_configure>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Catalog_Product_Composite_Configure</catalog_product_composite_configure>
            </rewrite>
     </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

This is my block content:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Composite_Configure extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Composite_Configure
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
echo 1; exit();
//        $this->setTemplate('mynamespace_mymodule/catalog/product/composite/reset.phtml');
    }

}
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in ..... /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create.php on line 105
```

Any idea what did I do wrong ? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is clearly conflict with your your rewrite block and file name

replace in xml `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Catalog_Product_Composite_Configure`

to `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Composite_Configure`

or switch to other way

Comment: thx I didnt have my coffee this morning yet :)